# border image repeat doesn't work

Tags: html, css

I want to make top and bottom borders with repeated image of a triangle. But can't achieve this result. I get just one triangle. 
How can I get the repeated triangle as in the pic?

[image]

my CSS:

```
border-style: solid;
border-width: 5px 5px 18px 20px;
border-image: url('../../img/triangle.png') 0 0 18 20 fill stretch;
```

Comment: Did you try adding `border-image-repeat: repeat;` property to your styling?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the shortcut "border-image" property. The `stretch` here corresponds to the `border-image-repeat` property. Set it to "repeat" instead of stretch.

Moreover, you are using the property "border-image-slice" in a wrong way. There is a good explanation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-image-slice).

You can find more about the border-image property in general [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_border-image.asp).

I advise you to use the verbose version when using a property for the first time:

```css
.banner{
    width:600px;
    height: 200px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 20px 0px 20px 0px;
    border-image-source: url('https://whatsarahread.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/113/2015/02/triangle-border.png');
    border-image-slice: 100% 0%;
    border-image-repeat: repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="banner"></div>
```

Comment: anyway, it's the same:( Even if with `border-image-repeat`

Comment: I added a more verbose version of it in my answer, that should do the job for you.

Comment: @Ren I added a working snippet, this should work for you. :)

Answer (score 0):

Use "repeat" instead of stretch as defined by Driblou.

```
    border-image: url('../../img/triangle.png') 0 0 18 20 fill repeat;
```